# Setting up mail client. Trying to connect only to the incoming server, avoid setting an outgoing server up

Tags: email

I have an Android 4 mobile phone and I'm trying to use the stock email client to connect to a webmail service.

The thing is that I am only interested in receiving my mail. I don't need to be able to send from my phone. **Is something like connecting only to the incoming server and leaving the outgoing server settings blank possible?** If not, are there any other email apps that offer this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the SMTP server details, try entering a server like `mail.messagingengine.com` and NOT entering any authentication details. The client will connect but because no auth details are provided, even if you attempt to send emails, the server just won't accept the connection and the emails will remain in the outbox.

Comment: I used the gmail smtp server and logged in with my gmail account. Thank you very much.